# Multiple comparison testing, who is the winner?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

Let's have four different running shoes, I want to test which ones are the fastest in terms of the average speed of the runner. I "hire" four different groups  of runners (each getting one version of the shoes) of the same size, sampled randomly from the population for an experiment where I let them run and measure their speed.

Question 1: What is the appropriate testing strategy?

(i) Pairwise difference in means of speed between groups with one of the available p-value corrections such as Bonferroni (6 pairs)

(ii) Taking one shoe as the baseline and check whether the others are faster or slower, also applying a p-value correction (3 pairs)

Question 2: How do I tell the winner in case I choose strategy (ii)?

Question 3: How do I determine the neccessary sample size for my experiment?

R-examples are also welcome.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem to me.

Comment: Is this a [tag:self-study] question?

Comment: Haha, I wish I had homework problems like that. Maybe my fault because I thought an example like that will be more understandable. The true interest is general: how to do correct statistical inference in experiments where I have independent groups with different treatments and need to find the winning treatment.

Comment: I would recommend (i) using Tukey hsd if you stick with your between-subject design. However, I suspect the power of a between-subjects design here would be very low and a within-subjects design would be preferable. In that case, use a version of the Bonferroni correction.

Comment: @David,That is very helpful! Any idea on how to determine sample size correctly? [This article](http://www.marketingdistillery.com/2014/08/10/multiple-abn-tests-in-marketing-with-anova-and-r/) says that you can basically just use  `pwr.anova.test` from the `pwr` package in R for Tukey's HSD test, but it seems to me like that is incorrect. Under ANOVA, I am looking for a sample size which allows me to compare the means for a given alpha, beta and MDE, however, under a procedure where p-values are corrected for family-wise error I assume I need higher sample size to get the same guarantees?

Comment: One issue is whether you are interested in power to detect any of the comparisons or the power to detect a specific one. If it is the former it will be similar to an ANOVA but that depends on the pattern of mean differences. If it is the latter then you would need a larger sample size.

Comment: Because I need to find the best alternative, I need a specific comparison, right? Then the question is, how much larger does the sample have to be?